# Dropdown menu (select) links not working

Tags: wordpress, select, menu

I'm using a select dropdown menu for mobile devices on a website that I'm working on, but when I select an item in the list, it doesn't take me to the corresponding page. I've looked at the source and the URL's are all in the right place, so I'm not sure what's wrong. I've tried it both on my computer and on my iPhone.

You can find the page [here](http://andersnoren.se/wptest/). Resize it below 500px to see the dropdown. I'm using the WordPress plugin [Dropdown Menus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dropdown-menus/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything that exists to submit the form. It's just a select menu with no form nor JS applied to it to trigger any action. Something like this would likely do the job [PHP - How to submit a select menu without a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029627/php-how-to-submit-a-select-menu-without-a-button)

Comment: Sometimes it's the most obvious thing. Thanks!